# Could someone explain chirality from a group theory point of view?

Tags: group-theory, rotations, dihedral-groups

While answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532426/a-question-of-h-g-wells-mathematics/532746#532746) my interest in the rotation/reflection group was piqued.

I personally know very basic group theory, not much more than what a group really is. I understand that the techniques I used in the answer to that question are similar to group theoretical techniques.

Could someone explain how chirality appears in $n$ dimensional objects living in $m>n$ dimensional space if and *only* if $n=m$ using group theory? Preferably (but not necessarily) giving some background on the techniques being used to better suit my current understanding of group theory.

Note thatwhen I say an $n$ dimensional object, I mean an object that can occupy a minimum of $n$ dimensions. A helix is thus a "three dimensional object", even if its topological dimension is 1.

Apologies if the question is too broad.

Comment: I am confused by "$m\gt n$ dimensional space if and *only* if $n=m$".

Answer (score 3):

When a dimension is added, one can rotate the axis of reflection and the added dimension by $180^\circ$ so that the reflection in the lower dimension is realizable as a rotation in the higher dimension. In the higher dimension, there is a rotation (determinant $1$) and a reflection (determinant $-1$) that affect the lower dimension in the same way.

To be precise (in the spirit of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/532527/13854)), consider a reflection in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that negates $x_n$
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&\dots&0\\
0&1&0&\dots&0\\
0&0&1&\dots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\dots&-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This can be lifted to an isometry in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ in two ways, as a reflection (determinant $=-1$)
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&\dots&0&0\\
0&1&0&\dots&0&0\\
0&0&1&\dots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\dots&-1&0\\
0&0&0&\dots&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
or as a rotation of $\theta=\pi$ (determinant $=1$)
$$
C=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&\dots&0&0\\
0&1&0&\dots&0&0\\
0&0&1&\dots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\dots&\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\
0&0&0&\dots&\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Since this determinant is a continuous function and the determinant of an isometry is $\pm1$, we cannot get from the identity to $A$ or $B$ via rotations. However, we *can* get to $C$ via rotation in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, and the action of $C$ is indistinguishable from the action of $A$ as viewed within $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus, chirality is lost when we add even one dimension.

Of course, you posted [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/532746), so perhaps I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: @Manishearth: I am sorry I can't help with algebraic understanding beyond linear algebra. I hope this helps, but let me know if I am totally missing the point.

Comment: @Landscape: not uncomfortable at all. Your comments were constructive and my answer is better now. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome and thank you for your understanding.

Comment: @robjohn I'd asked this question to get a better understanding of group theory. I already know the matrix approach :P

Comment: @Manishearth: I figured as much, considering you had written the answer I cited. I meant no offense, but this is what I could offer, and there weren't any other answers.

Comment: @robjohn None taken :) It's fine, this is a nice answer, not what I wanted that's all.